# binary search on c++ with comparison

Tags: c++, binary-search

I would like to perform a binary search on c++, on a sorted vector V.
In particular, I am not interested in finding a exact value of the entry of the vector. I would like to find the position j of the entry which satisfy V[j-1] <= X < V[j], where X is an input values.

for example:
for a vector v={1, 4, 7, 12, 17, 55} and X=8, the function should return 3.

Can I use the STD function binary_search, with O(log(2)) complexity?

And how?

Many thanks,

Al.

Comment: Shouldn't it return 7?

Comment: binary_search is only a function to look whether or not an entry is present, it does not return an index. @Armin He wants to return the index that holds the first value bigger than X.

Comment: @Egari Then it should be 3.

Comment: He says he doesn't want a value returned, he wants the index. However, your example doesn't satisfy V[3] <= 8 <= V[4] since V[3] = 12 and V[4] = 12. Did you mean to return 3 instead?

Comment: @Armin Indeed, I'm guessing he forgot zero based indexing

Comment: @all, Yes, I forgot the zero based index. Sorry for that. I am going to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your requirement, the correct STL function to use is upper_bound. Syntax:

```
upper_bound(V.begin(),V.end(),val)-V.begin()
```

Will return the 0 based index you seek.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers!!

Answer (score 8):

The standard functions for this are upper_bound and lower_bound. Read these

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

If you scroll down these pages a bit, you will find examples which should make things clear :)

Answer (score 4):

A note on the functions Bartosz linked:

- `upper_bound(begin, end, value)` returns the *first element greater than* the given value. This is the *end* (or one-past-the-end) of the interval where it could be inserted and preserve ordering
- `lower_bound(begin, end, value)` return the *first element not less than* the given value. This is the *beginning* of the interval where it could be inserted

So in practice:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 4, 7, 12, 17, 55};
int x = 8;
auto first = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
auto last = std::upper_bound(first, v.end(), x);
```

should give `first == last && *first == 12`. This is because the half-open interval `[first,last)` where `x` could be inserted is empty.

Note that this is generally more useful than what you actually asked for, because

```
std::vector::insert(iterator, value)
```

inserts *before* the given iterator, so you can always use the result of `upper_bound` here.